# How to write Maclaurin Expansion of sin(x) using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I want to write a recursive function to calculate the Maclaurin Expansion of sin(x). It goes like this: 
`sin(x)=x-(xˆ3/3!)+(xˆ5/5!)-(xˆ7/7!)+(xˆ9/9!)`...

```
    double sin(int n, double x){ // n is the exponent, x is the value
    if(n == 1)
        return x;
    if() // WHAT TO SET THE CONDITION TO ?
        return sin(n-2,x) - (pow(x,n-2)/fact(n-2)); // fact is a function I have to calculate the factorial
    else
        return sin(n-2,x) + (pow(x,n-2)/fact(n-2));
    }
```

I am having problems with setting the if condition, so that one time I add values, the next time I subtract values.

Comment: `if(even(n))` ?

Comment: @wally well the n number has to be an odd number.

Comment: Ah ok, how about `if(!even((n-1)/2))`?

Comment: @wally Thanks that worked! I also had to make a couple of changes. I will post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You would probably be better changing the specification of `sin(n, x)` so it would properly cope with an even value of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double sin(int n, double x){ // n is the exponent, x is the value
  if(n == 1)
     return x;
  if( ((n-1)/2) % 2 != 0)
     return  sin(n-2,x) - (pow(x,n)/fact(n)) ;
  else
     return  sin(n-2,x) + (pow(x,n)/fact(n)) ;
}
```